# How to store one entity in Redux Store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using `Normalizing State Shape` for my Redux Store and it looks like this:

```
  entities: {
    users: {
      list: [], // <-- list of all my users
      loading: false,
      lastFetch: null,
    },
  }
```

I got stuck on what should I do if someone opens up a website directly on the user's detail page. For example: `{WEBSITE_URL}/users/1`. The Redux Store is empty and I need to request only one entity. Should I:

1. fetch the whole list, put it in the Store and select one requested entity?
2. fetch only user #1, put it in the Store user list (`entities.users.list`), set `lastFetch` to null *(this is because if someone will redirect to list next, he will fetch the new list again. Clearly the pervious list didn't have all users)*, and display user #1 from the list.
3. fetch only user #1, put it in the Store in separate place. For example in `selected` field of `users`:

   ```
    entities: {
      users: {
        list: [], 
        loading: false,
        lastFetch: null,
        selected: null // <--- HERE
      },
    }
   ```

What solution do you think is the best? Do I need `selected` field at all? All tutorials and courses don't mention this scenario, only scenario how to fetch the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same dilemma.

My approach is always — **3.** I'm creating selected/single state to load data and one additional `action` (e.g. clearSelectedUser, clearSelectedPost) to clear data from the store on component unmount.

I'm also using Redux Saga to fetch data (do async operations) and this works good as combo. I really like the idea of having neat components without async calls in it.

However, I also found it *acceptable* to use component state (with `useState` hook) and do data fetching from a component directly (without Redux Saga or the store) in this particular case (entity single page/screen).

Option **1.** will not work if you get paginated data from your API. You'll just complicate things.

Option **2.** I agree with you on that one.

Comment: So If someone opens up a list page (you fetch your items), and then click on particular item, do you fetch for a single item again or you pick it up from the list?

Comment: I always think that data should be freshly fetched when user opens the single page. Why? Because if you don't have an auto-refresh system in your app, feed (home page / listing page) will have data that is not up-to-date, so it is logical to fetch single item each time user wants to get details about that particular instance. I hope that makes sense to you. I would really love to hear your opinion on that one too.